# ViewContainerRef implementation source

Tags: angular

where is implementation of `ViewContainerRef` abstract class in angular source? I tried but couldnt find.

[abstract class source link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fbf40bf4000944c06458472142ca967ef8d3b1d/packages/core/src/linker/view_container_ref.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I found it in under render3 path. Maybe someone needs this, [link to source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b071495f9216324783a8c4daca077acf9850292e/packages/core/src/render3/view_engine_compatibility.ts)